# How to use a regular expression to match the interface type and number, and 'Trunk' and 'LoopBack' do not match

Tags: regex

I want to use a regular expression to extract the interface type and number from a lot of commands.And these interfaces do not include 'Trunk' and 'LoopBack'

I tried this regular:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\-\/]+\s[0-9\-\/]*
```

but 'Trunk' and 'LoopBack' cannot be excluded.

Here are some examples of commands

```
interface Ethernet 2/0/0 xxxx
interface vlan12 xxxx
interface Trunk10 xxxx
interface LoopBack 1/0/0 xxxx
```

Comment: What is the tool or language that you are using? Which number do you want to match, and what is xxxx?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
^(?!.*(?:Trunk|LoopBack))[a-zA-Z0-9\-\/]+\s[0-9\-\/]*
```

**or this:**

```
^(?!.*\b(?:Trunk|LoopBack)\b)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\/]+\s[0-9\-\/]*
```